# MobilePush Exclude devices issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

With MobilePush the documentation clearly states that the way it determines which devices are sent the message is as follows:

1. Based on criteria that is selected go and get the contacts that have a device registered that match the criteria
2. Get all the devices that match that contact
3. Send the message to all those devices. Even though a device might not match the criteria specified in #1

Is there a way to prevent messages being sent to devices that do not meet a specific criteria? I am using attributes on device registration to build the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

After working with Salesforce Support and also our Solution Engineer a solution that we worked on was to at logout change the contact Key to the device ID. This ensures that only the correct devices are mapped to a contact that we would target a message to. Hope this helps others.